# Getting strange error when running the following function

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am trying to do something like

```
HTML('slider1') = someimage;
```

But my `HTML()` function is not returning `document.getElementById('slider1');`

[image: This is the error am getting on chrome]

```
function HTML(id){
    if(typeof value !== undefined){
        return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to a function? Shouldn't this be `var someimage = HTML('slider1');` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to assign some image through innerHTML, you may update your function to something like this

```js
function HTML(id){
    if(typeof value !== undefined){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
}

HTML('slider1').innerHTML = someimage;



//OR



function HTML(id, htmlChunk){
    if(typeof value !== undefined){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = htmlChunk;
    }
}

HTML('slider1',someimage);
```

Comment: Hey Satwik, Thank you, your solution is working but can you explain why my solution wasn't working.

Comment: '
You are trying to assign a value to another value returned from function "HTML". 
**HTML('slider1') = someimage; **
is not same as
**document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = someimage;**


function in your code is returning innerHTML of slider1
for example

**<div id="slider1">
Hello
</div>**

then

**HTML('slider1') = someimage; **

is executed as

**"Hello" = someimage;**

which is an error
'

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` allows the identifier to never have been declared before.

```
function HTML(id){
      if(typeof value == "undefined")
      {
          //do nothing
      }else{
          return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
          }
}
```

You can also try

```
 if(typeof neverDeclared === typeof undefined) //also no errors and no strings
```